# Why doesn't Object.prototype.toString produce more meaningful output?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript

Why doesn't Object.prototype.toString return a string representation of an object? I don't see any use for the current output and it seems that it would be more useful for the toString function to be the equivalent of JSON.stringify.

Is there a particular motivation or reason as to why `({ val : 1 }).toString()` produces `"[object Object]"` instead of something like `'{ "val": 1 }'` ?

Comment: Your presumption is that `Object.prototype` knows enough about the containing type to produce a meaningful string representation.  It probably doesn't.  When you call a method on an object, you're generally not calling   it on `Object.prototype`; you're calling it on the actual object.

Comment: See also [Array Prototype toString() vs Object toString()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33769209/102937) and [Is it possible to override JavaScript's toString() function to provide meaningful output for debugging?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6307514/102937)